# Excel Date Column not Correctly read

Tags: c#, excel, datetime

I am reading a date column from Excel as Such

```
var y = DateTime.FromOADate(GetExcelCellValue(range, rowIndex, DateColumnNumber));

private dynamic GetExcelCellValue(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range, short? row, int col)
{
    var cell = (range.Cells[row, col] as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range);
    return cell == null ? null : cell.Value2;
}
```

but I get an error that exception =

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.DateTime.FromOADate(double)' has some invalid arguments"

and when I used

```
var x = DateTime.FromOADate(Convert.ToDouble(GetExcelCellValue(range, rowIndex, DateColumnNumber)));
```

I get a date value of 30/12/1899

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Per [Microsoft specification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `DateTime.FromOADate()` method expects a `double` type parameter as can be seen below

```
public static DateTime FromOADate(double d)
```

and your `GetExcelCellValue()` method doesn't return a `double` type and so the error.

In your second case, you are explicitly casting it to `double` and you don't get any error because of that.

You can change your `GetExcelCellValue` method to return a nullable double instead.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

private double? GetExcelCellValue(Range range, short? row, int col)
{
    var cell = (range.Cells[row, col] as Range);
    //using null coalescing operator.
    return cell ?? cell.Value2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you!

but, I now get an error:
{"Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.__ComObject' to 'double'"}

and what's confusing is that when I explicitly cast, I don't get an error but the date is converted wrongfully

Comment: Is your `cell.Value2` always of type `double`? Or it can be any type?

Comment: It could be of any type.

Comment: That's typical and in such case; I would consider verifying the excel data and make sure that the `cell.Value2` data is of fixed type and  not dynamic type; which will make it more complex.

Comment: It's not fixed for the file, but I always know that for this particular column it will be a date and read as OLE automation date  in the form of a double